# Azure caching group strategy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-caching

I have a page with one main query with a bunch of filters on it, maybe 9 different dimensions.

I currently check my azure cache for the query parameters.  If it's there, I take that.  If not, I query sql and update the cache.  All of that is working nicely.

My problem is that if I update the data in the database I'd like to invalidate all the cached items associated with my query.

My hope is that there's a "group" key or something like it.  That way, I could invalidate an entire group of cached key/value pairs.

Is there a way to invalidate a group of caches in azure?  Or is my best bet to invalidate the entire cache? (which I don't know how to do either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache invalidation is typically done through notifications. The Shared Cache service (where you set it up through the portal and select a size from 128MB-4GB) does not support notifications.

The In-role cache that was introduced in June 2012 supports notifications and is part of the 1.7 SDK. Which cache type are you using?

Here's a [reference page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/) for getting started with in-role caching. And here's a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914137) for notifications.

Comment: I'm using shared cache at the moment.  I don't see how notifications would help me. For example if I want to invalidate "GroupA" how do notifications do that?  

It looks like regions and tagging might be better? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914155 That way I could put everything in one region, then use tagging to have identify "GroupA". Is that right?

Comment: Yes, regions work as well. And... again, supported in the new in-role caching, but not shared cache.

Comment: Great, it looks like as soon as I have access to it I can just switch it over in my web.config, add my regions/tags and be good to go.